# DataContractSerializer: can't deserialize because of changed property type

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

I have a property named **Lender** which previously was a *string*, and has since changed to the complex type *Lender*. I thought an implicit operator overload would resolve the transformation from a string to an object, but it doesn't, and deserialization fails.

Can I fix this in any way, or must I refactor my code for backwards compatibility?

Before:

```
class AnObject {
  string Lender { get; set; }
}
```

After:

```
class AnObject {
  Lender Lender { get; set; }
}

class Lender {
  public string Name { get; set; } // Previously the string property on AnObject.

  public static implicit operator Lender(string name) {
    return new Lender(name);
  }
}
```

Exception:

*Error in line 1 position 249. Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to "transition" the XML into the new format by replacing the text nodes under the *Lender* node with the *Lender* object serialized using the DataContract serializer.

Answer (score 2):

You implemented `implicit operator` in wrong class, it should be in `Lender`.

```
public class AnObject
{
    public Lender Lender { get; set; }
}

public class Lender
{
    public Lender(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Lender(string name)
    {
        return new Lender(name);
    }

    public static implicit operator string (Lender lender)
    {
        return lender.Name;
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
var obj = new AnObject();
obj.Lender = new Lender("lender");
```

and via implicit conversion

```
var obj = new AnObject();
obj.Lender = "lender";
```

---

Edit: Would the infamous dynamic do? Even if it works, it's scary.

```
public class Lender
{
    public Lender(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AnObject
{
    private Lender _lender;

    public dynamic Lender
    {
        get { return _lender; }
        set
        {
            _lender = value is string ? new Lender(value as string) : value as Lender;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I get for trying to write pseudo-code. I've corrected my question now ... thanks! :)

Comment: That's a brilliant question! I'm not sure my compilation settings even permits _dynamic_ but I'm sure going to try it out. I'll get back to you when I've tried! :)